# Can I scale a text box numerically without stretching the type?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

The type does not scale if I drag the side-handle of the text box, but when I adjust the width numerically it gets stretched. Is there a way to size a text box (I need it to match the width of other text columns) without scaling (distorting) the text.

Comment: It *is* a duplicate; Please review my answer here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10538/scaling-a-text-box-in-illustrator-cs6-without-scaling-text/10543#10543 I've updated it to reflect your specific issue. However, it is essentially the same answer.

Comment: furthermore, the answer to that question does not answer my question.

Comment: There must be a better way. Using the direct selection tool only works if you directly select each corner individually and then adjust the width numerically. Otherwise, the text gets stretched. Also, your answer to that question is not the selected answer. So, it's confusing to wade through everything that is there. I really think this question is different. ..but you have moderator power and I don't so you closed it and deleted my comment.

Comment: Just hold the option/alt key and click-drag around one corner.. then enter the numbers you want. You don't have to individually select every corner. I didn't delete your comment. The system did. And "wade through everything" ? There are only 4 answers.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't actually work. The answer that you point to on the other question is inadequate. The answer above in the comments, sadly, does not work for me with the current version of Illustrator on a Mac. I really think my question is worthy of an official and unique answer. ...but you have the power and I don't. How can I appeal to have this question opened back up?

Comment: hmm.. [**Seems to work just fine in Illustrator CC2015 here.**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tzweD.gif)